# Magento moving telephone field to to create new account page

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

Is there any easy way to move existing telephone field in Create new Customer Account page section

I know telephone field is present in New Address section , I don't want to create a new customer attribute ,

So far i have tried answer provided in [Adding tel number field to new acount page “create account” page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/18354/adding-tel-number-field-to-new-acount-page-create-account-page/25180#25180?newreg=dfdf3088c27c44ad93c4b132542973b0) , but didn't helped ,

I have magneto version 1.7.0.2 ,any help would be highly appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

//Open following file.

```
app\design\frontend\base\default\template\persistent\customer\form\register.phtml
```

Comment the following if condition or write the telephone filed out side the if condition.

```
<?php if($this->getShowAddressFields()): ?>
```

More reference link : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/110844/magento-1-9-how-to-display-telephone-on-registration-form

For example :

//Write below code out side of if condition and then try.

```
 <div class="field">
                    <label for="telephone" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Telephone') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" name="telephone" id="telephone" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getFormData()->getTelephone()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Telephone') ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('telephone') ?>" />
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: This above mentioned line appears at two places , could you please post the code snippet what to replace , as i have already tried the solution mentioned n the link , It didn't worked for me  .

Comment: Thanks , that helped , Now i can see a telephone text box on the New account creation page , But i can't see that information getting stored anywhere in the Admin page , telephone field in the admin page is still blank , But i am not getting any error also . How to store it in DB

Comment: Need to debug in controller. Check post parameter in this action(createPostAction) with file path : app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php. you will find the telephone parameter in post data. do not change filed name.

Comment: Thanks Jitendra , I have not changed the field name , Steps done : Moved the telephone field outside the If condition, Able could see a text field appearing on the Create account page  Telephone -textbox with required value ,But data is not getting saved any where , I think it's could be because of  it is part of billing address form, I verified in all the Customer related tables, it is not getting saved anywhere .

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow this steps to give telephone field in registration form.

**STEP 1**   You have to place the following code in your custom module layout file

```
<customer_account_create translate="label">
    <label>Customer Account Registration Form</label>
    <remove name="right"/>
    <remove name="left"/>

    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="customer/form_register" name="customer_form_register" template="modulename/register.phtml">
            <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="customer.form.register.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" translate="label">
                <label>Form Fields Before</label>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
</customer_account_create>
```

**STEP 2**   Create the register.phtml file in following path **app/design/frontend/theme_name/default/template/modulename/register.phtml**

**STEP 3**   Copy the register.phtml file in following path **app\design\frontend\base\default\template\persistent\customer\form\register.phtml**

**STEP 4**  relace that register.phtml file into local module path **app/design/frontend/theme_name/default/template/modulename/**

**STEP 5**  Check the following coding and inside the if condition put true or else remove the if condition.

```
<?php if($this->getShowAddressFields()): ?>
```

**STEP 6** You can see the telephone field in registration form with address fields.